# Group theory. Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $I$ be a group and $J$ its subgroup. Prove that $xJ = Jx = J$ for any $x \in J$.

I don't really understand how to prove it. I need some explanation of this get ready to pass exam

Comment: So you need to show that $xJ\subseteq J$ and $J\subseteq xJ$. Can you show one of these inclusions?

Comment: ...how do you define "subgroup" without this property?

Comment: I understand I have to show that left coset is equal to right coset. I don't really know how to show these inclusions

Comment: A non-empty set J ⊆ I is a subgroup of I if for
all x, y ∈ I, x y−1 ∈ I

Answer (score 4):

Since $J$ is a subgroup, for all $x,y\in J$ we have $xy\in J$. So, for all $y\in J$, $xy\in J$, i.e., $$xJ\subseteq J.$$ Similarly we prove that $Jx\subseteq J$. For other hand, note that, for all $x\in J$, $x=xe\in xJ$ and $x=ex\in Jx$. Therefore $$J\subseteq xJ\cap Jx$$ and so $xJ=J=Jx$.